# Tensor Flow neural network model predicting unrelated data also

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

### Neural Network Predicting unrelated data

My problem is There are 3 paths the object can follow Left, Right and Zigzag. I was training the neural network on one path suppose Left. And when I test the same neural network model in Right data it predicts really well but it shouldn't do that.
The function create_train_model(...) is for training the neural network and getting the weights and biases of the model. And function evaluate_model(...) is to predict next point given a set of previous points.

```
def create_train_model(Xtrain, ytrain):
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    _, num_inputs = np.shape(Xtrain)
    _, num_outputs = np.shape(ytrain)

    keep_prob = 0.9

    weights = {
        'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_inputs, n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
        'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, num_outputs], 0, 0.1))
    }

    biases = {
        'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1], 0, 0.1)),
        'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2], 0, 0.1)),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_outputs], 0, 0.1))
    }

    X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, num_inputs),  name='X')
    y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, num_outputs), name='y')

    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(out_layer - y))
    # # cost = tf.losses.huber_loss(y, out_layer)
    # # cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, out_layer)
    # cost = tf.losses.hinge_loss(y, out_layer)


    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    # Initialize variables and run session
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        for i in range(epochs):
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost],
                               feed_dict={X: Xtrain, y: ytrain})

        weights = sess.run(weights)
        biases = sess.run(biases)
    sess.close()

    return weights, biases

def evaluate_model(w, b, X, Xtest):
    weights = {
        'h1': tf.Variable(w['h1']),
        'h2': tf.Variable(w['h2']),
        'out': tf.Variable(w['out'])
    }

    biases = {
        'b1': tf.Variable(b['b1']),
        'b2': tf.Variable(b['b2']),
        'out': tf.Variable(b['out'])
    }

    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        print(sess.run(weights))

        print(sess.run(biases))

        pred = sess.run(out_layer, feed_dict={X: Xtest})

    return pred
```

The data has (x,y) coordinate in each time sequences 1,2,3,...N, with labels. I obtained the data for left by looking the label index and corresponding coordinates for that label. And time shifting them to get features for Neural Network. For 4 timeshift, I will have 8 features data and the output of the neural network is the next point in that motion.
Please help, I am stuck in this for really long I tried everything with no progress.

To Train the model:

```
    time_history = 4
    Train_Left, Train_Waggle, Train_Right = seperate_class_data(xy_train, time_history)

    Train_Right_X = Train_Right[0]
    Train_Right_Y = Train_Right[1]


    Train_Left_X = Train_Left[0]
    Train_Left_Y = Train_Left[1]

    Train_Waggle_X = Train_Waggle[0]
    Train_Waggle_Y = Train_Waggle[1]

    num_inputs = np.shape(Train_Left_X)[1]
    num_outputs = np.shape(Train_Left_Y)[1]


    print("Training Left Model")
    weights_left, biases_left = create_train_model(Train_Left_X, Train_Left_Y)
    weights_waggle, biases_waggle = create_train_model(Train_Waggle_X, Train_Waggle_Y)
```

To Evaluate The Model:

```
    X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, num_inputs),  name='X')
pred_left = evaluate_model(weights_left, biases_left, X, Test_Left_X)
pred_waggle = evaluate_model(weights_waggle, biases_waggle, X, Test_Waggle_X)
```

Comment: Could you also add the lines that you use to start training and evaluating the model with the functions you've defined in your post.

Comment: Hi, I added the training and evaluating phase of the process also.

Comment: For your `evaluate_model` function could you try this out: remove `X` as a function parameter and move ` X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, num_inputs),  name='X') ` to inside of your evaluate_model function on the first line. Rerun the code and do you still get the same result

Comment: pred_error = evaluate_model(weights_left, biases_left, Test_Right_X)
I plotted pred_error and the model still accurately predicts the Right Path. Even though the model parameter are for Left Path